# ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre una variable global static y una variable de clase, static?

Tags: c++, struct, class

Estoy estudiando más características de C++ por mi cuenta, y me he topado con `static`, ¿qué diferencias hay entre declarar un `static int x = 2` como una variable global, y declarar lo mismo dentro de una clase o un struct?

PD: También me gustaría conocer el funcionamiento de un método con `static`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`static` tiene varios usos:

- En variable independiente:

  ```
  static int algo = 5;
  ```

Esa variable, aparte de tener duración *durante toda la vida del programa*, **solo es visible en el archivo fuente en la que se declara**; es decir, si en 2 archivos `.cpp` declaras 2 variables `static int algo`, **cada una de ellas es independiente de la otra, y solo son visibles en el propio archivo**.

En C++, se puede conseguir el mismo objetivo mediante `namespace` anónimos:

```
namespace {
  int Algo = 0;
}
```

Lo cual consigue el mismo efecto: las variables así declaradas **solo son visibles en el archivo fuente en el que se declaran**.

- En variable-miembro de clase:

  ```
  class Class {
    static int Algo;
  };
  ```

Una variable-miembro de una clase así declarada, **no necesita una instancia de la clase para poder accederla**; es decir, no necesitas

```
Class instance;
instance.Algo = 0;
```

Puedes, directamente, hacer

```
Class::Algo = 0;
```

Lo cual implica que **no ocupa espacio en cada instancia**, sino que ocupa **1 única posición de memoria** durante toda la vida del programa.

- En variable automática:

  ```
  int algo( void ) {
    static int X = 10;

    return ++X;
  }
  ```

Así usadas, mantienen su ejecución entre llamadas: La primera vez que llamas a `algo( )`, devuelve `11`. La segunda vez, devolverá `12`; la tercera vez, `13`, ...

También presentan una peculiaridad: en los demás *modos de empleo*, **no está definido cuando se inicializarán** las variables, en relacion a los archivos fuente en el que se declara; si tiene 3 archivos fuente, con 1 variable `static` en cada uno, **no sabes el ordén** en el que se inicializará cada una: si primero las de un archivo o las de otro.

`static` en variables automáticas, sin embargo, **se inicializan la primera vez que las uses**, llames desde donde llames a tu función.

Comment: Ojo. Tu último ejemplo es de una variable estática a nivel de función, que es diferente a una variable estática global y una variable estática dentro de un objeto.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Si, lo se. Es que me pareció que `static` en variables automáticas debía de aparecer en una respuesta sobre `static` aplicado a variables.

Comment: En ese caso, te falta especificar que las variables estáticas a nivel de función se inicializan en el primer uso de la función. Por otro lado: no existen las variables automáticas estáticas... si es estática no es automática.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Lo indico, justo en el último párrafo :-p Y tienes razón en lo otro, es un sinsentido llamar `automático` a una variable estátca. ¿ `Variable interna de función` mejor ?

Comment: Perdón. Despiste mío (voy a por un café...). El nombre técnico es "*Function-level static variables*". Yo lo traduciría como "Funciones estáticas a nivel de función".

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Ok. Edito. Y tómate uno a mi salud :-)

Answer (score 4):

La diferencia se encuentra en el alcance de la variable ( scope ) mientras que la variable global x puede ser accedida desde cualquier parte del programa de forma

```
cout<<x<<endl;
```

si la declaración es dentro de una clase solo puedes acceder a ella haciendo referencia primero a la clase que la declara.

```
cout<< miclass::x << endl;
```

I el alcance de la variable **x** declarada en **miclass** esta definido por la clase en la que es declarada.

Comment: Sí pero debe haber alguna otra, porque si declaro con 
`static int x;` en una clase, y hago lo mismo en una variable global, al nombrar x otra variable global en otro .cpp no me da un error de link, si no le pongo static si me lo lanza, ¿qué quiere decir esto?

Answer (score 3):

> ... declarar un `static int x = 2` como una variable global ...

hace que el tipo de enlace de x sea "internal linkage"; va a haber una `x` distinta en cada unidad de traducción. Si está declarada en un header, cada cpp que lo incluya va a tener su propia declaración de x, independiente de los otros cppeces.

> ... y declarar lo mismo dentro de una clase o un struct?

Es otra cosa muy distinta; en este caso se va crear una única x que va a ser la misma para cada instancia de tu clase o struct; tenrás la misma x para todos.